# RVEST select an item from 'drop down' list and submit form

Tags: r, rvest

I am using `rvest` to scrape a website to download all the data in tables. Step 1 is working. I am not getting the Step 2 correctly:

Step 1:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
url<-'http://www.ahw.gov.ab.ca/IHDA_Retrieval/ihdaData.do'
sess<-html_session(url)
sess %>% follow_link(css='#content > div > p:nth-child(8) > a') -> sess
sess %>% follow_link(css='#content > div > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(10) > td > a') -> sess
```

Step 2:

```
pg_form<-html_form(sess)[[2]]
filled_form <-set_values(pg_form, `displayObject.id` = "1006")
d<-submit_form(session=sess, form=filled_form)
```

I am not sure how to submit the selected form. Do I need to use Selenium instead of rvest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to use RSelenium. You can scrape this particular site using rvest and httr, but it's a little tricky. You need to learn how to send forms in http requests. This requires a bit of exploration of the underlying html and the http requests sent by your web browser.

In your case, the form is actually pretty simple. It only has two fields: a `command` field, which is always "doSelect" and a `displayObject.id`, which is a unique number for each selection item, obtained from the "value" attributes of the "option" tags in the html.

Here's how we can look at the drop-downs and their associated ids:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

url <- "http://www.ahw.gov.ab.ca/IHDA_Retrieval/"

paste0(url, "ihdaData.do") %>%
GET() %>%
read_html() %>% 
html_node('#content > div > p:nth-child(8) > a') %>%
html_attr("href") %>% 
{paste0(url, .)} %>%
GET() %>%
read_html() %>%
html_node('#content > div > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(10) > td > a') %>%
html_attr("href") %>% 
{paste0(url, .)} %>%
GET() %>%
read_html() -> page

pages <- tibble(id = page %>% html_nodes("option") %>% html_attr("value"),
                item = page %>% html_nodes("option") %>% html_text())
pages <- pages[which(pages$item != ""), ]
```

This gives us a listing of the available items on the page:

```
pages
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   id    item                                                                    
#>   <chr> <chr>                                                                   
#> 1 724   Human Immunodeficiency Virus (HIV) Incidence Rate (Age Specific)        
#> 2 723   Human Immunodeficiency Virus (HIV) Incidence Rate (by Geography)        
#> 3 886   Human Immunodeficiency Virus (HIV) Proportion (Ethnicity)               
#> 4 887   Human Immunodeficiency Virus (HIV) Proportion (Exposure Cateogory)      
#> 5 719   Notifiable Diseases - Age-Sex Specific Incidence Rate                   
#> 6 1006  Sexually Transmitted Infections (STI) - Age-Sex Specific Case Counts (P~
#> 7 466   Sexually Transmitted Infections (STI) - Age-Sex Specific Rates of Repor~
#> 8 1110  Sexually Transmitted Infections (STI) - Quarterly Congenital Syphilis C~
```

Now, if we want to select the first one, we just post a list with the required parameters to the correct url, which you can find by checking the developer console in your browser (F12 in Chrome, Firefox or IE). In this case, it is the relative url "selectSubCategory.do"

```
params <- list(command = "doSelect", displayObject.id = pages$id[1])
next_page <- POST(paste0(url, "selectSubCategory.do"), body = params)
```

So now `next_page` contains the html of the page you were looking for. Unfortunately, in this case it is another drop-down selection page.

Hopefully by following the methods above, you will be able to navigate the pages well enough to get the data you need.